# Path analysis: Mediation and linear regression reporting

Tags: regression, spss, linear, mediation, amos

Let's say I'm testing this relationship in a path analysis in SPSS AMOS to answer these 2 research questions:

1. Does worker's moral have a significant positive relationship with organisation performance?
2. Does authentic leadership mediates the relationship between worker's moral and organisation performance?

[image]

Now, I use a SPSS AMOS path analysis to run this test. The results shows that there is a positive relationship between moral and org performance of 0.372, lets assume that this is significant, so I have my answer to the first research question. Would the path analysis use a linear regression to come up with the 0.372 as there is only 2 variables in this case and I assume it is a linear regression?

However, for the second research question on the mediation effects, would the 0.372 also be considered the direct effect of the mediation analysis? Usually when one reports mediation, we report the indirect and direct effects separately. Can I report the 0.372 as the direct effect in the presence of the mediator of authentic leadership?

It just seems strange that the linear regression results and the results of the direct effect of my mediation analysis are the same in my writeup so just wanted to check to see if this is normal?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, 0.372 would be considered the direct effect and yes, your path analysis is expected to produce the same slope coefficient as a multiple regression model. This is the case here because your path (mediation) model is saturated. It is equivalent to a multiple regression model in which moral and leadership are simply included as correlated predictors (rather than estimating the regression path from moral to leadership). Both models are saturated and reproduce your observed (co)variance and mean structure perfectly.